# php form wont submit with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a dashboard page, and for the easiest solution I've made the entire page a form (as there are several drop downs scattered across the whole page). I want to implement a feature that can submit the form every 30 minutes, be it with JavaScript, jQuery or anything else, but when I've tried it just refuses to execute the code, so I tried going back to something basi such as submitting the form when the drop-down is changed via "OnChange".

Here is an example snippet of a seperate page with some code from my dashboard page. This in itself should be working but I just can't see why it won't execute the code, maybe I'm missing something obvious? Can you help me fix this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submit_my_form(myfield)
{
   myfield.form.submit();
}
function submitForm() {
    document.getElementById("branchForm").submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php   
$branch_array = array(
        array(1,"BRANCH 1",1, "http://BRANCH.BRANCH1:1"),
        array(2,"BRANCH 2",1, ""),
        array(3,"BRANCH 3",3, "http://branch3:3"),
        );
?>
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST" name="branchForm" id="branchForm">
    <select name="query" id="query" class="select" onChange="submit_my_form(this);">
    <?php
    foreach ($branch_array as $x) { // populate select box with branches available from array

        echo '<option value ="'.$x[0].'"';
        if (isset($_POST['query']) && $_POST['query'] == $x[0]) 
        {
            echo ' selected="selected" >'.$x[0].". ".$x[1].'</option>'; 
        } else { 
            echo ' option="'.$x[0].". ".$x[1].'">'.$x[0].". ".$x[1].'</option>'; 
            }
    }
    ?>
    </select>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Refresh" class="btnRefresh" />
        <input type="button" value="go" name="click" onClick="submitForm();" />
    </form>
    <?php echo "<br/>Output: {$_POST['query']}"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Nothing happens when the drop-down is changed, and nothing happens when the "go" button is pressed.

Comment: please put the rendered html than server code

Comment: Did you take a look at the JS console? Are there any errors?

Comment: Do you have to use javascript/jquery etc or can you use php to do so?

Comment: `myfield.form.submit();` should just read `myfield.submit();` because it is the form you're trying to submit

Comment: `document.getElementById("branchForm").submit();` That ID does not exist in you HTML... Your form's ID is 'query'... Another question is why you have the buttons in your form backwards? refresh is submit and submit is button... Why?

Comment: @Raphioly-San the element exists right after the _first_ php array, `<form action...`

Comment: @AhsN you're right... I should get a downvote for not reading good enough... Still... Why do it this way...? It would be more sane to do `submit_my_form(document.getElementById("branchForm"));` ...

Comment: @FilipeFerreira I don't mind using PHP if it's possible, but I did prior research and it didn't appear as though PHP could manipulate the page this way. The error console shows:
`Error: TypeError: document.getElementById(...).submit is not a function.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't mind using jQuery, here you go:

```
var form = $("#formId");
$("select[name=selectField]").on("change", function(e){
    form.trigger("submit");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zt8zz1j5/

All it essentially does is listen for change on the select element, and simply triggers the submit event on the form. Of course you'll need to change the names and IDs to fit your code, but I'm sure you can handle that :), and remember to include jQuery in the document.

And for the button it's the same thing. You listen for the 'click' event and then trigger 'submit' on the form.

Comment: Thanks for this; unfortunately I can't get it to work with my PHP code too and I have no idea why. The regular submit button works but when I add this code and modify the jQuery names to fit my form, it still refuses to do anything.

Comment: Could you upload a Fiddle with the rendered HTML and Javascript?

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x23jLmxh/) It looks like its the submit button, as soon as I remove it, the drop-down change works. Is there any way to keep the button while still having the drop-down execute?

Comment: Ohh I see, the answer to that was so simple! Thank you both very much, I believe I can get somewhere with this now. (On a side note I'd completely missed out the jQuery window.load function by accident haha...)